# How do I view the source of a page generated mostly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

On this Yelp page:

http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=auto+repair&find_loc=70163&ns=1#l=g:-90.1266860962,29.9067341681,-90.0243759155,29.9959757119

The first result is GR Automotive. But when I do View Page Source and Ctrl+F for GR Automotive I get no results.

I believe this is because the text I want is generated by javascript.

How can I view the new page source which is generated by javascript?

I need to be able to manipulate the data on the page, but it's not in the html source, and I don't want to use the API since the main portion of my code is in Autohotkey. The URL version of the yelp API also doesnt seem to work with the sample example code.

Comment: @EternalHour has the correct answer below. You need to use the developer tools to view the DOM has it has been manipulated by the js.

Comment: It's actually a pretty good question, but asked in a horrible way.

Comment: @JakeParis, how should he have asked it better?

Comment: @Optimus, I edited it to read better before you read it. :)

Answer (score 1):

***Answer based on your question title:***

This question does not appear to be about programming, but you need to view the information a different way in order to see the DOM. Instead of "view page source", use "inspect element".

***Answer based on your edited question:***

In order to manipulate Yelp listings, you will need the Yelp API.
[General documentation](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation)
[Business API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, you certainly can't manipulate it  through view page source in the browser.

Comment: For example if I wanted to retrieve the business name "GR Automotive" using a web browser object, how would I do so?

Right now I am declaring an IE browser object, and then I navigate to the yelp page, and within ie.document.innerHTML, I cannot retrieve the business names.

Comment: If the API wasn't required, anyone would be able to modify the business details which is not good.

Comment: @Samuel How do I go about accessing the JSON object for different pages? I know you linked it but how did you create that link? Thanks! This looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

After your post on [http://ahkscript.org](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5167)

Remember that View Page Source does not give you the live Source

I still took a look at it... and it can be done just fine with a normal IE browser COM object from ahk

Example:

```
url := "http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=auto+repair&find_loc=70163&ns=1#l=g:-90.1266860962,29.9067341681,-90.0243759155,29.9959757119"

wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.visible := true
wb.Navigate(url)

while wb.readyState!=4 || wb.document.readyState != "complete" || wb.busy
    continue

sleep 100

while (wb.document.getElementsByClassName("throbber-overlay")[0].style.display != "none")
    continue

msgbox % wb.document.getElementsByClassName("natural-search-result")[0].innertext
return
```

I don't really know what you tried before but with an IE COM object you can access the dhtml without much hassel.

But you always need to wait long enough for the elements you need to fully load when trying to access them this way.